# spell checking and TeXworks

Tags: 11.10, latex, dictionary, spell-checking

When I use TeXworks there is no automatic spell checking.
If I go Edit -> Spelling, the only option I have is none

How can I enable spell checking?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a section of the TeXWorks manual in which there is the reference to a guide on how to use dictionaries.

The link it refers to is [this](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/SpellingDictionaries), so you should place your personal dictionaries in the folder /usr/share/myspell/dicts.

One easy way to add them is to install them.
I suppose that if you use LibreOffice then they are installed by default.
If not, you can simply install the packages named `myspell-XX`, where XX stands for your language.

You can easily find them with apt-get and auto-completion or via Synaptic.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually seen that but I already had a bunch of dictionaries in that directory. However apt-get'ing the same dictionary I normally use fixed the problem magically!

Comment: I tried this. But still it doesn't show up in my spelling sections.

Comment: You can please share this answer in tex.SE (for others' benefits) here  : http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235313/52071

Comment: @MycrofD not sure, that question is for Windows :)

Comment: Oh I see. My bad. And yes my problem was solved only after I installed as you said.. and then I had to symlink the respective files..as solved below by @SPSJNU2006-2014

Answer (score 15):

In case you already have LibreOffice installed, the `en_US.aff` and `en_US.dic` files are already on your system in the `/usr/share/hunspell` folder. In this case, just symlink these two files into `/usr/share/myspell/dicts` and you are done:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic /usr/share/myspell/dicts/
sudo ln -s /usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff /usr/share/myspell/dicts/
```

You can do so for all dictionaries you find in `/usr/share/hunspell`.

Restart Texworks afterwards.

You can see *Texworks* > *Edit* > *Spelling* > *Unites-States* now. Click it.

Also change *Texworks* > *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Editor* > *spell-check-language* > *English-United-States*.

You are done after restarting.

Comment: It's 16.04 and I still have to manually create these links...

Comment: I again came across this issue in Ubuntu 18.04. My TeXworks did offer the `de-lu` instead of the `de-de` language for no good reason. When I uninstalled the `myspell-de-de` package and marked the `hunspell-de-de` package as installed manually (to avoid it gets uninstalled together with the `myspell-de-de` package), the issue was solved. So it seems nowadays, better get rid of the `myspell-**`packages. The package description in Ubuntu 18.04 says it can be safely removed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have hunspell dictionaries in the language you need already installed. Look for them in the folder `/usr/share/hunspell` and maybe you don't have to install a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 on an old toshiba laptop. The config file of TeXworks looks for its dictionaries in /usr/share/hunspell. And it is not easy (if possible at all) to change this behaviour. But one can copy (or move) the dictionaries that have been installed. Or download them from Open Office; they will be with oxt extension but these are zip files and making the extension from oxt to zip does the job, then unzip these. You need the *.aff and *.dic files only (plus the rules for hyphenation if any). 
Then you need root access to copy or move these to /usr/share/hunspell. If you have it, just open terminal in the folder where the files are:
sudo cp  /usr/share/hunspell/filename
And that is it.
Another advantage: If you want to switch to TeXstudio then from its config menu you can select the folder where the dictionaries are. So you can select the same.